# varification email is not sending to email address using smtp in local sever in ubuntu

Tags: python, django, email, ubuntu

For my django project.i created a registration form where as usual the user is asked for his email address for the varification.Now the problem is when i test the registration form as user and pass my email address,it shows that a varificatio has sent to my email address but there is no email i found my email inbox.

now the question is how do i send email to my email address using local server not the live sever In Ubuntu.In mention i am using smtp and i have put the following in my settings.py file..

```
EMAIL_FROM = 'raihncse43@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

and this is my full settings.py file..

```
import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join


sys.path.insert(0, '../..')

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ROOT_PATH = abspath(dirname(__file__))

ADMINS = (
# ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)


EMAIL_FROM = 'raihncse43@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
 'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'test.db'
}
}

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Montevideo'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

SECRET_KEY = '#$5btppqih8=%ae^#&amp;7en#kyi!vh%he9rg=ed#hm6fnw9^=umc'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
# Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
# 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'example.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'example.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
join(ROOT_PATH, 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'social.apps.django_app.default',
'example.app',
)

LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
}

SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'social.backends.amazon.AmazonOAuth2',
'social.backends.angel.AngelOAuth2',
'social.backends.aol.AOLOpenId',
'social.backends.appsfuel.AppsfuelOAuth2',
'social.backends.behance.BehanceOAuth2',
'social.backends.belgiumeid.BelgiumEIDOpenId',
'social.backends.bitbucket.BitbucketOAuth',

)

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/done/'
URL_PATH = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY = 'social.strategies.django_strategy.DjangoStrategy'
SOCIAL_AUTH_STORAGE = 'social.apps.django_app.default.models.DjangoStorage'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH_SCOPE = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]
# SOCIAL_AUTH_EMAIL_FORM_URL = '/signup-email'
SOCIAL_AUTH_EMAIL_FORM_HTML = 'email_signup.html'
SOCIAL_AUTH_EMAIL_VALIDATION_FUNCTION = 'example.app.mail.send_validation'
SOCIAL_AUTH_EMAIL_VALIDATION_URL = '/email-sent/'
# SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_FORM_URL = '/signup-username'
SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_FORM_HTML = 'username_signup.html'

#For Facebool Login using Social Auth
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY='149560535145169'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET='8db9dc18b04804895af8cf7a18fe5a4b'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_APP_NAMESPACE = 'kothaymtl'
#SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']


SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
'example.app.pipeline.require_email',
'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)

try:
from example.local_settings import *
except ImportError:
pass
```

now is that enough to do that or what actually i am missing here...

Comment: Do you actually have a mail transfer agent running on port 1025 on your local host?

Comment: no ,i don't have any mail transfer agent @ lanzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to setup an smtp server on your local machine. [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html) a great software for smtp emails.

The easiest way is to setup postfix to use your gmail account to send out email. Here is a link to a nice tutorial for the same:
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/

After configuring Postfix, you can set the `EMAIL_PORT=25` or just leave it to default, and you are ready to send out emails.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gmail account for sending the mail, you would have to use smtp.gmail.com as the host with port 465 and encryption 'ssl'